# Deploy google function with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to deploy a google cloud function using terraform. The function requires the function to be zipped. I need a hello world project with terraform and nodejs. I've been trying for the past few days to set it up, but without a success.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what problems did you have? If you could show your code, the steps you take and the errors you get that would be help people answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sample Terraform

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "test" {
    name                      = "[FunctionName]"
    entry_point               = "helloGET"
    available_memory_mb       = 128
    timeout                   = 61
    project                   = "[GCPProjectName]"
    region                    = "us-central1"
    trigger_http              = true
    trigger_topic             = "[PubSubTopic]"
    trigger_bucket            = "[StorageBucketName]"
    source_archive_bucket     = "${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}"
    source_archive_object     = "${google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name}"
    labels {
    deployment_name           = "test"
    }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name = "cloudfunction-deploy-test1"
}

data "archive_file" "http_trigger" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "${path.module}/files/http_trigger.zip"
  source {
    content  = "${file("${path.module}/files/http_trigger.js")}"
    filename = "index.js"
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "archive" {
  name   = "http_trigger.zip"
  bucket = "${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}"
  source = "${path.module}/files/http_trigger.zip"
  depends_on = ["data.archive_file.http_trigger"]
}
```

Sample nodejs

```
/**
 * HTTP Cloud Function.
 *
 * @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.helloGET = function helloGET (req, res) {
    res.send(`Hello ${req.body.name || 'World'}!`);
};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. How do you zip the bundle? Just building and then zipping it?

Comment: @aphex if the nodejs source file is in the right relative path (see the `source` in the `archive_file` `data` block), terraform will zip for you!

Comment: yeah, but what is the file called and how do you reference it in the terraform template???

Comment: in the same directory as the module is defined, the template is looking for `files/http_trigger.js` (see the `content` of the `archive_file.http_trigger`. That file is then renamed to `index.js` inside of the zip, which is then deployed to a storage bucket